# Create two tables customer_data and order_data in SQL in a single execution via PHP

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers_data (
 id int(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 INVOICE_ID varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
_NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
MOBILE bigint(12) NOT NULL, 
GSTIN varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
_ADDRESS varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
EMAIL varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
_STATE varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
MODE varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
_DATE date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(), 
total_qty int(11) NOT NULL, 
total_amount decimal(40,2) NOT NULL, 
total_sc_gst decimal(30,2) NOT NULL, 
Round_Off float(2,2) NOT NULL, 
grand_total decimal(50,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

***customer_data created sucessfully.***

But there is an error in order_data regarding foreign key. Remember I want to create these two table in a same time.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_data (
 id int(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 cus_id int(20) NOT NULL, 
ITEM varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
HSN varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
QTY int(15) NOT NULL,
 RATE decimal(40,2) NOT NULL, 
S_C_GST decimal(30,2) NOT NULL, 
TOTAL decimal(50,2) NOT NULL,
 _DATE timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 FOREIGN KEY(cus_id) REFERENCES customers_data(id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I got this error.

> #1005 - Can't create table test. (errno: 150 "Foreign
> key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: I recommend laying out your SQL better. Also only tag a single RDBMS, MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: `#1005 - Can't create table test.` - you do not provide SQL for `test` table creation.

Comment: run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and see the LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR section for details.

Comment: `int(20)` not exists. Data length is deprecated and ignored for integer datatypes. Replace with `int`.

Comment: It seems fantastically pessimistic that a customer would generate only a single invoice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using MySQL. You have not used Constraint with Foreign Key. Try the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_data (
 id int(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 cus_id int(20) NOT NULL, 
ITEM varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
HSN varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
QTY int(15) NOT NULL,
 RATE decimal(40,2) NOT NULL, 
S_C_GST decimal(30,2) NOT NULL, 
TOTAL decimal(50,2) NOT NULL,
 _DATE timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 **CONSTRAINT <FK_NAME>** FOREIGN KEY(cus_id) REFERENCES customers_data(id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: It is syntax. you have to do if it is mysql

Answer (score 0):

Making the table "at the same time" is not the problem you need to solve, (it's not possible anyway).

You can't make a foreign key if the data type is different from the data type of the referenced column.

`order_data.cus_id` is an INT column.

`customers_data.id` is an INT UNSIGNED column.

Change either one or the other data type, so they are the same.